# Get a project to work on

Tags: project-bidding

I would like to work on a project for free. I am willing to help someone. I have very good skills but I haven't worked for a while. I want to get into the freelancing business and I would start with a project for free. Where could I post an add like this???

I can to a lot of things, but I don't have unlimited time. All I want is to get myself going back again and to use the project as a reference in the future.

Comment: What have you tried? What kind of projects are you looking for? Have you tried legwork? Have you talked to friends and families?

Comment: Programming, I am little rusty but I have knowledge PHP, Python, Mysql

Comment: That's not answering the probing question...

Comment: Go to local church/charity/non profit organization and offer your help as volunteer programmer/developer. Talk to family, relatives and friends maybe you will find someone who needs your skills or a project to be done without having money to afford it. Post an ad in your local city newspaper or website offering yourself for free development/programming with the reason to build a portfolio or CV. Or do some open source app of your choice and release to the public, this will be good and ready to do, just pick an idea and go.

Comment: If your goal is to get a task more easily, I don't think this is a good idea: proposing to work for free will raise distrust, giving a feeling of "I am not sure to manage". Bid for what you are worth.

Comment: Build a project for yourself. Create something to catalog the books you own, or dvds, or build an address book.. etc.... Your own web site (so you can promote it)

Comment: If you're good at something, never do it for free.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get into the Freelancing then Join a freelancing website like Upwork or Freelancer. Create a profile, add your education and experience, take skill tests, etc. and start applying to the projects which fits best on your skills. You can't offer a Free service on these portals, but you can reduce your rate per hour/charge less fee as compared to your competitors and earn some good feedback and reputation. Once you have that, you can increase the price depending upon the actual value of the work. Always remember, **good work and client satisfaction is the key to success** on Freelancing Portals.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the answer in the comments, but a church or charity or local organisation will not want a rusty amateur fiddling about with their sites on a 'not sure what I can still do but I will try' basis.

The best advice given so far is to buy a domain and cheap hosting, and build a site for yourself. It could be a CV site, or a profile site, or just a site to practice on.

When you are a bit more confident in your abilities, and now have something to point to, find a local organisation or family/friend/contact that does not currently have a site, and offer to build one for them for free. That way they have nothing to lose. But you have to commit to doing it. You cannot be half arsed about it.

Now you have your practice site, and a genuine site to point to, you can start pitching for small, easy jobs. Once you have one under your built, you can add them as a portfolio to your profile site, and then you are up and going.

Good luck. Technology has moved on and continues to move at an exciting rate. But you will come up to speed quickly with some enthusiasm and commitment.

Answer (score 0):

As before me you already got the answer and that's right.
Well my suggestion is to start coding and developing your project and host on free servers available and mentioned below.
1. [Open Shift](https://www.openshift.com/)
2. [000Webhost](https://www.000webhost.com/)

As I saw your previous comments you mentioned that 
"Programming, I am little rusty but I have knowledge PHP, Python, Mysql"
 So I provided you the links to free web servers.

Both supports PHP.
and also provide a sub-domains for free.

Then as you done you may mention the url in your cv and then talk to people and showcase your skill for free.
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

A good way to get coding experience is also to join open-source projects. You can fix small issues to start with to get your hands dirty. This directly contributes to job success because it builds up your profile on github (many employers will ask to see your github activity).

Here, for example, is a list of trending PHP projects on github: https://github.com/trending/php

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Sheryl and think you should find a small project and easy, to begin with. Paid lower than the competitors and mention in your cover letter, you have an experience but you are new at upwork.

After you get a task you should do it perfectly to get good feedback from the client.

Happy working